# Adding a ProducerInterceptor - Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, interceptor, producer

I am trying to intercept the messages before they get serialized, and I see that there is already a interface called ProducerInterceptor, that can be used in order to modify the records. After making a class which implements that interface and modifies the data, where do I need to put the new class, do I have to modify some files?

Comment: Why kafka add producer and consumer Interceptors you will get more from this [article](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-42%3A+Add+Producer+and+Consumer+Interceptors#KIP-42:AddProducerandConsumerInterceptors-Motivation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating the KafkaProducer object, pass it in the properties e.g.

```
Properties producerProps = new Properties();
producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, "fully qualified name of your interceptor class");
//... add other properties
KafkaProducer<String,String> kProd = new KafkaProducer<>(producerProps);
```

Comment: Even if I put the properties in that way, the interceptor will only show up when I put these extra commands `--producer-props bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 interceptor.classes=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.MyInterceptor acks=all`. Also, how can I add a value to the producerRecord?

Comment: Its simple. Please refer to the javadoc - https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html